# VLC player doesn't work in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: apt, video, plugins

I have Installed and re-installed VLC player multiple times in Ubuntu 15.10. But every time I am encountering following warning..

```
Processing triggers for vlc-nox (2.2.1-3) ...
No plugins in /usr/lib/vlc/plugins
WARNING: Regenerating VLC plugin cache failed.
Please run 'vlc-cache-gen -f /usr/lib/vlc/plugins' manually.
Setting up vlc (2.2.1-3) ...
```

The message is saying

> WARNING: Regenerating VLC plugin cache failed.

Even I tried to install from Ubuntu software Center. But still VLC player is not running.

Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: Did you to do as asked, run the vlc-cache-gen manually? What happened?

Comment: Try the following single terminal command: `export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0 && vlc`

Comment: Read and follow what is in the 4th line: `Please run 'vlc-cache-gen -f /usr/lib/vlc/plugins' manually.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this to forcefully reset the plugin cache:

```
sudo /usr/lib/vlc/vlc-cache-gen -f /usr/lib/vlc/plugins
```

If it fails, try to purge all VLC packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc*
```

Then reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```